# How can I combine two newtheorem environments so that one is continuing the numbering of the other plus some additional numbering?

Tags: numbering, newtheorem

I want to achieve having two different environments for my lemmas, say lem1 and lem2, such that Lemmas written by \begin{lem1} \end{lem1} are numbered within the section, and if I add lemmas by \begin{lem2} \end{\lem2} they pick up the numbering of lem1 but with an additional numbering within consecutive lem2-lemmas until the next lem1-lemma comes.

Hope this does not sound too confusing, but I think an example clarifies pretty well what I mean:

```
1. Section

2. Section

   2.1. Subsection 

      Lemma 2.1             <- lem1

   2.2. Subsection

      Lemma 2.2             <- lem1

      Lemma 2.3             <- lem1

      Lemma 2.4 (I)         <- lem2

      Lemma 2.4 (II)        <- lem2

      Lemma 2.5             <- lem1

      Lemma 2.6 (I)         <- lem2

      Lemma 2.6 (II)        <- lem2
```

I have achieved something similar but not quite what I want by:

```
\newtheorem{lemma1}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{lem1}[lemma1]{Lemma}
\numberwithin{lemma1}{section}

\newtheorem{lemma2}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{lem2}[lemma2]{Lemma}
\numberwithin{lemma2}{section}
\renewcommand{\thelemma2}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{lemma1} (\Roman{lemma2})}
```

This leads to

```
1. Section

2. Section

   2.1. Subsection 

      Lemma 2.1             <- lem1

   2.2. Subsection

      Lemma 2.2             <- lem1

      Lemma 2.3             <- lem1

      Lemma 2.3 (I)         <- lem2

      Lemma 2.3 (II)        <- lem2

      Lemma 2.4             <- lem1

      Lemma 2.4 (III)       <- lem2

      Lemma 2.4 (IV)        <- lem2
```

Can someone please help me? :-)

Thank you in advance

Edit for clarification: I need that Lemma 2.**3** is followed by 2.**4** (I)

Edit after having read the proposed solution:
The solution also works when having defined

```
\newtheorem{firsttheorem}{Proposition}
\numberwithin{firsttheorem}{section}
```

with lemma (in the solution) replaced by firsttheorem. Then one can write

```
\begin{sublemmas}

    \begin{whatever is defined as firsttheorem}

    \end{whatever is defined as firsttheorem}

\end{sublemmas}
```

and everything works perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell LaTeX when to start subnumbering and when end it.

The idea here is the same as `subequations`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]

\newcounter{parentlemma}
\newenvironment{sublemmas}
 {%
  \refstepcounter{lemma}%
  \setcounter{parentlemma}{\value{lemma}}%
  \edef\theparentlemma{\thelemma}%
  \setcounter{lemma}{0}%
  \renewcommand{\thelemma}{\theparentlemma\space(\Roman{lemma})}%
  \ignorespaces
 }
 {\setcounter{lemma}{\value{parentlemma}}\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}

\section{Test A}

\begin{lemma}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}

\section{Test B}

\begin{lemma}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}

\begin{sublemmas}
\begin{lemma}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}
\end{sublemmas}

\begin{lemma}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}

\begin{sublemmas}
\begin{lemma}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}
\end{sublemmas}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use `\label` after `\begin{sublemmas}` to get a reference to the common number. And also arbitrary text between the sublemmas, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem as Lemma 2.2 is followed by Lemma 2.2 (I). It should be Lemma 2.2 and then Lemma 2.3 (I)

Comment: @lunskra Sorry for the misunderstanding. See new code.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much