# When clicking the reference to a lemma in a custom sublemma-environment I created, I am brought to the beginning of the section and not to the lemma

Tags: hyperref

In [How can I combine two newtheorem environments so that one is continuing the numbering of the other plus some additional numbering?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588621/how-can-i-combine-two-newtheorem-environments-so-that-one-is-continuing-the-numb#) I found out how to create a subnumbering for my lemmas.

Now I have the following problem: When I click on a reference to the sublemmas later in the text, I am brought to the beginning to the section containing the lemma. What do I have to change in the example provided below in order for the reference's location to be correct?

(I tried to add /phantomsection in front of the sublemmas, but that didn't do the trick.)

I created an example worksheet which clarifies what I mean:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\usepackage{lipsum}  

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[pdfpagemode=UseNone,bookmarksopen=false,colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,citebordercolor=blue,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}


\newtheorem{firsttheorem}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[firsttheorem]{Lemma}


\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{firsttheorem}{section}

\newcounter{parentlemma}
\newenvironment{sublemmas}
 {%
 ~\refstepcounter{firsttheorem}%
  \setcounter{parentlemma}{\value{firsttheorem}}%
  \edef\theparentlemma{\thefirsttheorem}%
  \setcounter{firsttheorem}{0}%
  \renewcommand{\thefirsttheorem}{\theparentlemma(\Roman{firsttheorem})}%
  \ignorespaces
 }
 {\setcounter{firsttheorem}{\value{parentlemma}}\ignorespacesafterend}
 


\begin{document}

\section{Test A}

\begin{lemma}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}

\section{Test B}
\textcolor{red}{I land here when I click~\ref{sublemmas1}!}
\begin{lemma}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}

\lipsum 

\begin{sublemmas}
\textcolor{red}{I want to jump here if I click on~\ref{sublemmas1}!}
\begin{lemma}
\label{sublemmas1}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}
\end{sublemmas}

I want to jump here if I click on~\ref{lemma2}!
\begin{lemma}
\label{lemma2}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}

\begin{sublemmas}
\begin{lemma}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}
\end{sublemmas}
\newpage

\section{Test C} 
When I click on~\ref{lemma2} I jump to the right location, but clicking on~\ref{sublemmas1} brings me to the beginning of Section Test B.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\renewcommand{\theHfirsttheorem}{\theparentlemma(\Roman{firsttheorem})}`

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much :) Can I somehow accept your comment as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
  \renewcommand{\theHfirsttheorem}{\theparentlemma(\Roman{firsttheorem})}
```

to the environment definition so that hyperref can create distinct destinations.

Comment: I just realized that something odd is happening:  when I click on the reference of the first "normal" lemma Lemma 2.1 in Section Test B, I get redirected to the beginning of Section Test A. Any ideas what the problem could be?