# When clicking on the reference to the first lemma in a section I am brought to the beginning of the section and not to the lemma

Tags: hyperref

**Updates are in bold**

Here [When clicking the reference to a lemma in a custom sublemma-environment I created, I am brought to the beginning of the section and not to the lemma](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/637896/when-clicking-the-reference-to-a-lemma-in-a-custom-sublemma-environment-i-create) someone helped me to fix the hyperrefs to the custom sublemma environment I created (see minimal working example below).

This solution brought up two new errors:

- When clicking on the reference to the first lemma in a section, I am brought to the beginning of the section (see minimal working example) (**solved**)
- When uploading the file to arxiv.org, the references to the lemmas do not work at all anymore.. (**only references to the sublemmas are not working, see updated working example**)

Can anybody please help?

Here is the example:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\usepackage{lipsum}  

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[pdfpagemode=UseNone,bookmarksopen=false,colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,citebordercolor=blue,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}


\newtheorem{firsttheorem}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[firsttheorem]{Lemma}


\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{firsttheorem}{section}

\newcounter{parentlemma}
\newenvironment{sublemmas}
 {%
 ~\refstepcounter{firsttheorem}%
  \setcounter{parentlemma}{\value{firsttheorem}}%
  \edef\theparentlemma{\thefirsttheorem}%
  \setcounter{firsttheorem}{0}%
  \renewcommand{\thefirsttheorem}{\theparentlemma(\Roman{firsttheorem})}%
  \ignorespaces
 }
 {\setcounter{firsttheorem}{\value{parentlemma}}\ignorespacesafterend}
 
\renewcommand{\theHfirsttheorem}{\theparentlemma(\Roman{firsttheorem})}

\begin{document}

\section{Test A}
\textcolor{red}{I land here when I click~\ref{firstlemmainsection}!}
\begin{lemma}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}
\lipsum
\section{Test B}
\begin{lemma}
\label{firstlemmainsection}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}

\lipsum 

\begin{sublemmas}
\begin{lemma}
\label{sublemmas1}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}
\end{sublemmas}

I want to jump here if I click on~\ref{lemma2}!
\begin{lemma}
\label{lemma2}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}

\begin{sublemmas}
\begin{lemma}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}
\end{sublemmas}
\newpage

\section{Test C} 
When I click in~\ref{firstlemmainsection} I get redirected to the beginning of Section Test A.




\end{document}
```

**Meanwhile I found out that when hovering over the hyperlink in my locally generated PDF it says ''/.../#firsttheorem.2.3(I)" but in the file generated by arxiv.org it is ''/.../#firsttheorem.2.3(I)%00''. Somehow arxiv.org adds a %00 which is causing the error.**

**I can locally recreate this problem by using the LaTeX-compiler instead of the pdfLaTeX-compiler.**

**I found the error: arxiv is not using the pdflatex-compiler per default so I had to add the command "\pdfoutput=1" within the first 5 lines of my main file.**

**Updated working example, which is actually working:**

```
\pdfoutput=1

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\usepackage{lipsum}  

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[pdfpagemode=UseNone,bookmarksopen=false,colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,citebordercolor=blue,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}


\newtheorem{firsttheorem}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[firsttheorem]{Lemma}


\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{firsttheorem}{section}

\newcounter{parentlemma}
\newenvironment{sublemmas}
 {%
  \refstepcounter{firsttheorem}%
  \setcounter{parentlemma}{\value{firsttheorem}}%
  \edef\theparentlemma{\thefirsttheorem}%
  \setcounter{firsttheorem}{0}%
  \renewcommand{\thefirsttheorem}{\theparentlemma(\Roman{firsttheorem})}%
  \let\theHfirsttheorem\thefirsttheorem
  \ignorespaces
 }
 {\setcounter{firsttheorem}{\value{parentlemma}}\ignorespacesafterend}
 


\begin{document}

\section{Test A}
% \textcolor{red}{I land here when I click~\ref{firstlemmainsection}!}
\begin{lemma}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}
\lipsum
\section{Test B}
\begin{lemma}
\label{firstlemmainsection}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}

\lipsum 

\begin{sublemmas}
\begin{lemma}
\label{sublemmas1}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}
\end{sublemmas}

I want to jump here if I click on~\ref{lemma2}!
\begin{lemma}
\label{lemma2}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}

\begin{sublemmas}
\begin{lemma}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}
\end{sublemmas}
\newpage

\section{Test C} 
When I click on~\ref{firstlemmainsection} it works.

When I click on~\ref{sublemmas1} in the PDF generated by arxiv.org nothing happens.


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the redefinition of `\theHfirstheorem` in the wrong place.

```
\newcounter{parentlemma}
\newenvironment{sublemmas}
 {%
  \refstepcounter{firsttheorem}%
  \setcounter{parentlemma}{\value{firsttheorem}}%
  \edef\theparentlemma{\thefirsttheorem}%
  \setcounter{firsttheorem}{0}%
  \renewcommand{\thefirsttheorem}{\theparentlemma(\Roman{firsttheorem})}%
  \renewcommand{\theHfirsttheorem}{\theparentlemma(\Roman{firsttheorem})}%
  \ignorespaces
 }
 {\setcounter{firsttheorem}{\value{parentlemma}}\ignorespacesafterend}
```

I also removed the stray `~`.

More simply,

```
\newcounter{parentlemma}
\newenvironment{sublemmas}
 {%
  \refstepcounter{firsttheorem}%
  \setcounter{parentlemma}{\value{firsttheorem}}%
  \edef\theparentlemma{\thefirsttheorem}%
  \setcounter{firsttheorem}{0}%
  \renewcommand{\thefirsttheorem}{\theparentlemma(\Roman{firsttheorem})}%
  \let\theHfirsttheorem\thefirsttheorem
  \ignorespaces
 }
 {\setcounter{firsttheorem}{\value{parentlemma}}\ignorespacesafterend}
```

Remember that in order to make arXiv to use `pdflatex` for your document you must specify

```
\pdfoutput=1
```

preferably at the very start of the document.

Comment: Nice! now the referencing is correct when I compile it. However, letting the file compile in arxiv.org the sublemma references are still not working at all (the regular lemma references work fine). I am a bit confused as to why arxiv isn't producing the exact same PDF?

Comment: I updated the working example accoring to the new arxiv-error: Meanwhile I found out that when hovering over the hyperlink in my locally generated PDF it says ''/.../#firsttheorem.2.3(I)" but in the file generated by arxiv.org it is ''/.../#firsttheorem.2.3(I)%00''. Somehow arxiv.org adds a %00 which is causing the error. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @lunskra Sorry, no idea.

Comment: I found the error: arxiv is not using the pdflatex-compiler per default so I had to add the command "\pdfoutput=1" within the first 5 lines of my main file. Thank you so much for your help, everything is working now. Maybe you could add this line to your solution as well?

Comment: @lunskra Added as requested